# Import pandas error

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting an error in Git Bash as I run my python code:

```
$ python Humiditypyth.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Humiditypyth.py", line 1, in <module>
     import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I have Anaconda installed and I checked in "python list" that pandas is installed. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you see if pandas is listed under  `pip freeze`

Comment: Try running `conda install pandas` from the command line, and if that doesn't work, try `pip install pandas`. You should also check to make sure pandas was installed by running `pip show pandas` from the command line. pandas isn't automatically downloaded with conda

Comment: pandas does not show up under `pip freeze`. i have done `conda install pandas` successfully. but it errors out for `pip install pandas`. It does not show up under `pip show pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a checklist

1. Do you have anaconda installed in the same python version that you are using? e.g. if python is calling python2.7 and python3 does python 3.6 you have to install anaconda in the right folder with either "sudo pip install anaconda" or "sudo pip3 install anaconda"
2. after that I think you still have to install pandas "pip install pandas" or "pip3 install pandas"

I might be wrong though I never used that library.

Comment: yes, everything is in Python 3.6. I have installed Anaconda with `conda install anaconda` successfully. However, whenever i run any `pip install`, it says: `$ pip install anaconda
Downloading/unpacking anaconda
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement anaconda
No distributions at all found for anaconda
Storing complete log in C:\Users\gdavidso\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log`. I tried pip install for just pandas and got something similar.

Comment: Wait that was a bold face lie. I somehow have Python 2.7 downloaded. How can I get rid of Python 2 and move it to python 3?

Comment: You can delete all the folders associated with python2.7 which should be in `"/usr/bin"` but you can find it with the command `"whereis python"` or `"which python"` If I'm not mistaken.
You can have both versions on your computer just make sure you are using the one where anaconda is installed. to install python3 just search on google it should be straight forward.

Comment: Ahh i figured it out. I ended up uninstalling python and anaconda and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 3):

Try

- python3.6 Humiditypyth.py. [try using sudo if it doesn’t help]
- pip3 freeze  - check if you can see pandas in there. If not do 
  pip3 install pandas

Comment: I just realized somehow I had Python2 installed instead of python 3. Still stuck though

Comment: please check your python3 path and run from there:
``` /usr/bin/python3 file.py ``` . Also make sure all your imports are installed.

Comment: I don not have `python3` in my python folder. Only `python3.exe`. Also when i type in `python` and tab over to autofill, i see `python2.7` (as well as both `.exe` files) but no `python3`